# How can I open the last opened file by vim and go to a specific line?

Tags: bash, open

I want a bash function to open the last file opened by vim and goes to a specfic line

I tried

```
vil()
{
   vim -c "normal! '\''0 :$1"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mark such as `'0` actually works in Ex mode as well, for example `:'0` will take you to the line of that mark, so for the first part, opening Vim on the last file edited, you can simply use:

```
vim -c "'0"
```

For the second part of jumping to a different line, you can simply use a separate `-c` with a number, which will jump to that line.

Putting it all together:

```
vil() {
    vim -c "'0" -c "$1"
}
```

Note again that this depends on `$1` being a valid line number, which you might want to check in the function... In any case, this should address the issue at hand in your question.